# Pastas drawable para dpi diferentes não aparecem no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, drawable

Não encontro as pastas drawable com as devidas resoluções no Android Studio. Só possui uma chamada drawable, onde devo colocar as imagens com as resoluções diferentes?

[image: Árvore de diretórios de um projeto Android no Android Studio, na qual é possível ver que apenas uma pasta drawable existe]

Comment: Olá, @Ablon. Use a opção de descrição das imagens para descrever a imagem como para uma pessoa que não enxerga, para fins de acessibilidade, e não para justificar o motivo de ela estar de um certo jeito.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode clicar no botão como na figura e mudar para Packages, daí você verá todas as seus arquivos que estão "ocultos", mas serão mostrados quando vc selecionar Packages.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá amigo... está vazia da mesma forma! Aparece as pasta mipmap, cada uma com sua resolução, mas pelo que pesquisei, aquelas são somente para ícones. Achei varias pastas drawable dentro de Libraries, porém isto está fora da pasta do meu projeto, e pelo que vi na internet, deveria está onde tirei o print

Comment: Olá novamente! Veja só, os icones os quais vc fala também são imagens, só que está colocado nesta pasta mipmap para tratar ela como icone de inicialização que é o ic_launcher.png. A pasta drawable é para vc colocar as imagens, que para adicionar ao projeto é necessário arrastar a imagem diretamente para dentro da pasta drawable. Pegue o arquivo imagem.png arraste e solte na pasta drawable.

Comment: Certo, mas drawable está vazia, não possuiu cada uma com sua resolução como vejo nos tutorial. Está certo isso?

Comment: sim. Pois agora você irá colocar sua imagem arrastando e soltando como falei e a resolução você define na hora que você arrasta o item para dentro da pasta drawable.

Comment: Deveria ter essas:[link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=pasta+drawable+android+studio&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=599&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=o4k2VcfCH8zxsAWYx4HwCg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=32RipF0xeiSb1M%253A%3B-tv-yiiN6x7GgM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ftableless.com.br%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2015%252F04%252FTree-do-Android-Studio.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ftableless.com.br%252Fa-pasta-res-e-os-resources-em-um-projeto-android%252F%3B408%3B648)

Comment: Você mudou como na imagem que eu mostrei acima? De ANDROID. para PROJECT Note que foi alterado de ANDROID para PROJECT.

Comment: Sim mudei, e continua do mesmo jeito

Comment: Coloca um print a opção PROJECT, caso não consiga no comentário coloca na tua resposta a cima, abaixo da figura que você colocou.